# Script is getting hang in ie browser only

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation, web-testing

I want to execute this code in IE11 but it goes in hang mode not clicking in yes button could not understand the reason meanwhile its working fine in chrome and FF

Tried with option -e --skip-js error

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture(' testcafe ie issue')
.page('https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/home');
test('testcafe ie issue', async (t) => {

const medicalCannabisImage=Selector('.wg-hdr-nav-img').nth(0);
const ageGatePopUp = Selector('.age-gate');
const pageContainser=Selector('div#app')

const yesAgePopUp = Selector('[data-auid="age-gate-primary"]');

await t.click(medicalCannabisImage);
if (await ageGatePopUp.exists) {
await t.click(yesAgePopUp);
}

});
```

I want to execute this code in IE11 but it goes in hang mode not clicking in yes button could not understand the reason meanwhile its working fine in chrome and FF.

Comment: I executed your test case in IE11 using the latest TestCafe version 0.23.3 and it passed. I recommend that you try the latest version if you have one of the previous versions. My IE version is 11.345.17134.0 just in case.

Comment: By the way, the test passed on my side because 'ageGatePopUp' didn't appear due to the 'Access Denied' error. It states that "You don't have permission to access "http://cannabis.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en_CA" on this server". Are there any restrictions for accessing this area?

Answer (score 0):

We've reproduced this problem and found that its cause is related to this GitHub issue:

[Not finding an element in IE11](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/1890)

The fix is on its way according to the team's comments.

**UPDATE**:

The fix is ready and is available in version testcafe@v1.0.0-alpha.2.